# PHP 6 sided die counting number of rolls

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and I am stuck. I'm trying an exercise where I am rolling a 6 sided die and counting the number of times it is rolled until there is X number of 1s rolled in a row. The code I have up until this point is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //Practiceing while and do while loops
$onecount = 0
$rollcount = 0
while ($onecount < 7) {
    $roll = rand(1,6);
    $rollcount ++;
    if ($roll!=1) {
        echo {$rollcount};
    }
    else {
        $roll=1;
        $onecount ++;
    }
}


?>
   </body>
</html>
```

I feel like I'm missing something very simple but I didn't know what else to do.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have parse errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for `$onecount = 0
$rollcount = 0` and not closing those statements, should that be your actual code.

Comment: and you have more errors that you think is valid syntax. In any which case, see the answer below, ask them now and given that you may have left the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `$onecount` variable when the role isn't 1, since the streak is broken each time it's a different number. Also, you probably want to do something after the while loops finishes and you have your total roll count.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I do what you are recommending? How do I "reset" the $onecount variable when the role isn't 1. I maybe starting with something over my head. Is there a resource that you recommend learning from?

Comment: By "reset" I just mean set it back to it's original value. So in this case, that would be: `$onecount = 0;`. As far as resources - there are plenty of good PHP tutorials out there. I would recommend doing some Google searches to find one you like.

Comment: Also - as mentioned in the comments above, make sure you clean up some of the syntax errors in your example. You're missing a couple semicolons.